# transfer an entry one from one HashMap to another

Tags: rust

I am using `hashbrown::HashMap` container in my project and would like to know if an entry from one `HashMap` can be transferred to another `HashMap` efficiently

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39874a7f23474e9b044889e94890a699

```
use hashbrown::HashMap; // 0.14.3

fn print(hash_map: &HashMap<u32, u32>) {
    for (k, v) in hash_map {
        println!("{k}: {v}");
    }
    println!();
}

fn main() {
    let mut h1: HashMap<u32, u32> = HashMap::new();
    h1.insert(1u32, 1u32);
    h1.insert(2u32, 2u32);
    h1.insert(3u32, 3u32);
    h1.insert(4u32, 4u32);
    h1.insert(5u32, 5u32);
    
    let mut h2: HashMap<u32, u32> = HashMap::new();
    h2.insert(6u32, 6u32);
    h2.insert(7u32, 7u32);
    h2.insert(8u32, 8u32);
    h2.insert(9u32, 9u32);
    
    print(&h1);
    print(&h2);
    let k = 5;
    if let Some((k, v)) = h1.remove_entry(&k) {
        // this is copying the data, if I'm not wrong
        h2.insert(k, v);
    }
    
    println!("\n");
    print(&h1);
    print(&h2);
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by copy. There's no way to transfer memory between structures without copying at least some memory. Furthermore, all moves in Rust are `memcpy`s.

Comment: looking for an equivalent of `C++` `std::unordered_map::extract` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/extract

Comment: Given that pointers to extracted elements remain valid, it seems that `unordered_map` must access all of its elements through an additional indirection? That is, the C++ version would appear not to move the map’s elements, but only pointers to them. Rust actually does move the elements. If you don't want this, you can get the C++ behavior by placing the values in some container external to the map — a `Vec` that outlives it, say, and storing only references to within the `Vec`, but this hardly seems worth it.

Comment: C++'s `unordered_map` uses a chained hash approach with a separate allocation for each entry which is what allows the `extract` API, but it causes `unordered_map` to be rather slow. I believe `hashbrown` uses an open-addressing approach instead which is faster but doesn't support this kind of API.

Comment: As far as I understand the implementation of hashbrown, it stores the actual data in an contiguous array (i.e. a Vec). So "extract"ing the "node" is not even a sensible operation you can do on a hashbrown hashtable (there is no data structure corresponding to a node physically stored within the table). As far as transferring data between HashMaps efficiently, moving from the old hash table and moving into the new one is the fastest way.